# I am trying to understand how pointers and arrays of pointers work. What am I not understanding in this program?

Tags: c, arrays, function, function-pointers

```
int main(){
  int i, department_quantity;
  char *passer[8];
  char *department_id = malloc(8);

  printf("Enter number of departments:");
  scanf("%d", &department_quantity);

  for(i = 0; i < department_quantity; i++){
      printf("Enter ID of department #%d\n", i + 1);
      scanf("%s", department_id);
      passer[i] = department_id;
  }

  string_array(&passer[0], department_quantity);

}

void string_array(char *array[], size_t length) {
    int i ;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("\n%s\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
   Enter number of departments:2

   Enter id of department #1

   hello

   Enter id of department #2

   world

   world

   world
```

I'm trying to understand why I'm not able to get the program to output the different user input i.e. hello world and not "world world". What am I not understanding about pointers here?

Answer (score 2):

`department_id` is just the same block of memory. For every input (every iteration) you are writing at that same memory address, effectively overwriting the previous content. So, at the end, all you have is the final word you've inputted. Note that `passer` will contain equivalent elements (the pointer is the same).

To fix this you need to allocate memory separately for each string. Something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < department_quantity; i++) {
    // ...
    department_id = malloc(8); // here
    scanf("%s", department_id);
    passer[i] = department_id; // now passer[i] is a different pointer each time
}
```

Or you can ditch `department_id` and go for `char passer[8][8]` which doesn't allocate dynamic memory and then simply `scanf("%s", passer[i]);`.

P.S. Using `scanf` in such a way is quite dangerous, since there is nothing stopping you from inputting a string that is too large to fit in the memory you've allocated. The usual approach would be `fgets(passer[i], 8, stdin)` where `passer` is `char passer[8][8]` - note `8` is given as the size of the buffer.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought I was doing wrong. How do I avoid that from happening? Cause no matter how I adjust things, I get "might not have been initialized".

Comment: @DeiDei So if i use a 2d array, wouldn't that create an issue for me when calling string_array() function?